# Animation doesn't work very well in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

I have a view (grey background) and another over it with a `UITextField`.

When I tap on the grey background, I want the view with the `UITextField` to disappear with an **animation (move to top)**

When I tap on the return key (virtual keyboard) the animation is smooth, but when I tap on the grey background, it disappears without animation. When I comment out the `vueRecherche.isHidden = true` in the completion, it's ok, but I want to hide it!

here is my function

```
private func fermeRecherche() {

        if self.constraintVueRecherche_Top.constant == -5 {
            return
        }
        self.txtRercherche.endEditing(true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

            self.constraintVueRecherche_Top.constant = -5
            self.vueFondGris.alpha = 0.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: { termine in

            self.vueRecherche.isHidden = true
            self.vueFondGris.isHidden = true
        })

    }
```

with this call, the animation is smooth :

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    fermeRecherche()
}
```

but not with this one :

```
let tap=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapFondGris(_:)))
vueFondGris.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func tapFondGris(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    fermeRecherche()
}
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting your `tapFondGris` code in main thread: `DispatchQueue.main.async { fermeRecherche() }`

Comment: Also you can add `.AllowUserInteraction` for the option in the method `UIView.animate`so it will be called on main thread..

Comment: thanks for your answers ... i try the both, but i have the same result.

Comment: Is `txtRercherche` a subview of `vueFondGris`? And `constraintVueRecherche_Top` is the top constraint of `vueFondGris`? So you want `vueFondGris` to "slide up and fade out"?

Comment: yes it's exactly that

Comment: Strange, I create an Xcode project with your code and it works :/

Comment: can you in your completion block, check if termine (is true) before executing the code ?

Comment: i add a if termine { ..... } but same result

Comment: the problem seems to be when i launch the fermeRecherche from the view ... when i dismiss the keyboard, the animartion is smooth